# Inter core communication in spike

Tags: riscv

When we use spike in the multicore mode using spike -p2, is there any way where we can simulate transfer of data from one core to the other, is there a program that can do so?

Comment: What are you looking to do? You can talk through memory like every multi-core does.

Comment: I want to have two rocket cores instantiated on an pga and i want them to send data between each other without the use of the cache coherence network, something like a mini noc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a mechanism is not currently in spike or rocket chip. You will need to design and implement it in either one.

Comment: OK so I need to edit chisel and make this happen on the rocket chip

Comment: Are there any other sources of documentation other than riscv.org where I could find these details

Comment: For modifying rocket chip, I would look at the docs produced by lowRISC (http://www.lowrisc.org/docs/). There design has some modifications, but it was done to rocket chip, so much of it should be the same.